# What is the time difference between Thor and The Avengers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011, the-avengers-2012

I am asking myself if there is a time difference between the events in *Thor* and *The Avengers*? Is Loki presumed dead a long time?

Answer (score 16):

Some unknown amount of time passed between the end of *Thor* and the start of *The Avengers*.  This timeline shows the best timeline of events in the Marvel Cinematic Universe that I know of, and it just has an ambiguous space of time between the end of *Thor* and *The Avengers*:

[image: Official Marvel Cinematic Universe timeline]

Given that timeline, it would be likely a few months.  At the end of *Iron Man 2*, Tony Stark hadn't begun construction on Stark Tower.  That was being completed at the start of *The Avengers*, so the time spent tearing down and rebuilding that building would be between "Day 4" and the start of *The Avengers*.

---

[A recent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45141/1027) indicated a more canonical answer.  There's roughly 1 year between the events of *Thor* and *The Avengers*.

Comment: Wow, looks awesome! Thank you for the timeline!

Comment: And for the explanation aswell.. :)

Answer (score 3):

### 2 years

According to the official chronology of the MCU, as presented by [*Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ), there is a 2-year gap between *Thor* and *The Avengers*. The official timeline reveals that the main events of *Thor* occurred in the spring of 2010, while the events of *The Avengers* unfolded in the spring of 2012.

[image: page of The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline illustrating the above][image: page of The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline illustrating the above]