# How long after The Avengers does Thor: The Dark World take place?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

During the events of *The Avengers*, Loki notes that the Bifrost is still destroyed:

> **Loki:** With the Bifrost gone, how much dark energy did the Allfather have to muster to conjure you here, your precious Earth?

In *Thor: The Dark World*, the Bifrost is already rebuilt and operational.

But at the beginning of *Thor: The Dark World*, Loki is brought before Odin, and the conversation they have feels as though they had not really discussed Loki's actions during the Avengers before.

How long has passed since the ending of *The Avengers*?

Comment: I had the impression that that scene took place just after *Avengers*, and then there was a time skip.

Comment: @evilsoup, even if there had been, weren't Thor, Sif and the other warriors using the Bifrost to go to other worlds to travel to the other realms to handle the uprisings?

Comment: @phantom42 The opening started with the backstory prologue.  It was followed by Thor delivering Loki to Odin.  Then Thor and pals are off handling the uprisings.  There's clearly an unstated time jump before that last one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Two years after the events of Thor, one year after the events of Avengers.**

This was discussed in an [interview with Kevin Feige](http://www.slashfilm.com/film-interview-thor-the-dark-world-producer-kevin-feige/), as being about a year or so:

> **That leads me to suggest you are keeping a time line in your mind with these movies. We know Iron Man 3 took place six months after The Avengers. Jane mentions that Thor 2 happens like two years after the original and Scarlett Johansson recently said The Winter Soldier is like two years after The Avengers. So Thor centric, where does Thor 2 take place after The Avengers? How long has he been away? We see almost the next scene after with the Loki scene.**
>
> Yeah. You know, we think it’s been at least a year from the end of The Avengers and that between Loki being sentenced to the dungeons and Thor finishing up putting out the fires between the nine realms that it’s been about a year, but it’s probably been a year before that since he was in New Mexico with Jane, so that’s the two years.

There was also an interview in Empire with Craig Kyle (the producer) who said it was about two years since the events of Thor, one year since the events of The Avengers. (Unfortunately, I can't find a link).

I think the scene with Odin reprimanding Loki takes place very shortly after *The Avengers*, and then time passes while Thor does the rounds.

There was a [two-issue prelude comic to Thor 2](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/42667/marvels_thor_the_dark_world_prelude_2_2012_1) from Marvel which includes that scene, and has it set immediately after Thor and Odin return to Asgard with the Tesseract at the end of *The Avengers* (that comic also shows the reconstruction of the Bifrost, and shows the dark magic Odin uses to send Thor to Earth).

Comment: Weren't Thor, Sif and the other warriors using the Bifrost to go to other worlds to travel to the other realms to handle the uprisings? That scene was before the conversation in the throne room with Loki.

Comment: It may be worth adding that the 'Loki brought before Odin' scene was a last-minute addition to the film.  That helps explain the disjointed nature of it and the scenes before/after it.  http://www.slashfilm.com/what-loki-scenes-were-added-to-thor-the-dark-world-and-what-did-joss-whedon-rewrite/

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about The Avengers, but definitely 2 years after the events of Thor: because Jane complains in The Dark World that Thor was gone for 2 years.

Comment: Right. And since Thor is before Avengers, that puts Dark World 0-2 years after Avengers.

Answer (score 2):

There was a two year window since the first events in Thor. It had been a year since the Avengers met and fought the Chitauri in New York.

It would seem Marvel is trying to keep their movie timelines and the real world timelines as in sync as possible. Movie production being what it is, I suspect this will start to slip over time.

Comment: I think Darcy was referring to the last time Thor was on Earth (the first film), wasn't she?

Comment: @alexwlchan, that was my understanding as well.

Comment: @alexwlchan that was also my impression. That it had been 2 years since the original Thor movie.

Answer (score 1):

##### Loki being sentenced to life imprisonment by Odin happened shortly after *The Avengers*, while most of the events of *Thor: The Dark World* took place approximately 15–21 months after *The Avengers*.

According to the official timeline of the MCU, which is published in the book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)*, the events of *The Avengers* took place in the spring of 2012, while most of the events of *Thor: The Dark World* (not including Loki's sentencing by Odin) happened in the fall of 2013. This shows that there is a gap of roughly 1 year and 3 months to 1 year and 9 months between the events of the two films.

[image: pages of the Official Timeline describing the above]

> But at the beginning of *Thor: The Dark World*, Loki is brought before Odin, and the conversation they have feels as though they had not really discussed Loki's actions during the Avengers before.

This part of *Thor: The Dark World* also took place in the spring of 2012 and after the events of *The Avengers*, according to the official timeline, suggesting that it took place shortly after the ending of *The Avengers*.

[image: section of the Official Timeline describing the above]